# "Php require section in composer is empty" - can't upload a package to the Marketplace

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, marketplace

I have a problem with uploading **new extension** version to the **Magento Marketplace**. The error message is **Php require section in composer is empty** 
My `composer.json` file hasn't been changed (since previous approved versions on Marketplace) and it contains only one dependency:

```
"require": {
  "magento/module-catalog": "~101.0.*"
}
```

I tried to add php dependency (tried different versions), but that doesn't help, error message remains the same.

Can't figure out what is wrong here? Have anyone experienced this issue on Marketplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"php require section" sounds like you need to require a PHP version now. For example to require any PHP 5.6 or 7.0 version:

```
"require": {
  "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
  "magento/module-catalog": "~101.0.*"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this trailing comma is not present in the composer.json archive. I have added require "php": "~7.0.*", and seems like it works now (doesn't work if I put php dependency AFTER catalog dependency).

Comment: But now Marketplace shows me another error "Can not read the archive" :) ... and I love it!

Comment: OK great, I removed the part about the syntax from my answer as well

Comment: Why double || ? and not single | ?

Comment: @Mr.K that's what the official composer documentation says: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#range But both seem to work

Comment: @FabianSchmengler thx :) Indeed I've seen in the Magento core that they use the signle instead of the double